# How to recover data from Windows 7 Overwritten by Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk

While installing Ubuntu 14.0.4, I selected Windows replace option. After installation of Ubuntu,my windows drives are not visible. I tried to recover the data using testdisk but I was unable to recover. While recovering data using testdisk NTFS new Volume is shown. I don't know how to recover. Are there any tools or any simple procedure to recover data?

Answer (score 0):

If TestDisk didn't work, I'm afraid your chances are not great... at this point your best bet might be to bring or send your hard drive to a reputable professional data-recovery service. While they are generally very good, they can be extremely expensive, and there's no guarantee that the files will be recoverable. So it depends on your financial resources and how important the data was. Probably your best bet is to just restore your latest backup and move on... if you didn't have backups, consider this a very painful life lesson to *always, always, always* back up your data on a regular basis. Online backup services and USB flash drives are inexpensive and easy ways to make backups.

Comment: I dint understand how to use testdisk.Nfts partition is still showing while using testdisk.I just asked,is there any other simple tool,which we can use to recover the data.

Comment: Or the OP can use RecuperaBit as mentioned in the linked Q. Disclaimer: I am the developer.